# Integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$ region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

If its all parameterized usually I can solve it, but I have a problem with integration in vagues regions, usually I dont know the right procedure to solve them.

The problem I need to solve is: given some region $D_R$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ exterior to the ball $B_R(0)$, prove that $\int_{D_R}1/r^a$ exists if, and only if $a>n$. Also proves that $\int_{B_R(0)}1/r^a$ exists if, and only if $a<n$.

Im not only interested in the solution, but the general idea about how to solve this kind of integral, is there some algorithm or something like?

Thanks.

Comment: **hint** change to polar coordinates.

Comment: That exactly the problem! What coordinates am I changing? If $D_R$ were parameterized I would know what to do but this region is too much general...I dont know how to change variables here.

Comment: Wait, so your question is actually "how to parametrize $D_R$?" If so I would suggest that you edit the question to make it clear, and also perhaps add the [tag:analytic-geometry] tag.

Comment: No, $D_R$ is not parameterized. There is a way to show that this integral exists, its not necessary to calculates. I just commented the parameterized issue because I can only work this way but want to understand how do people works with integral in this kind of more generic regions.

Comment: Do you know what $B_R(0)$ is? Especially what it is in polar/spherical coordinates? If so what is its complement $D_R$?

Comment: Is the ball with radius $R$ and center at the origin. I know how to work until $\mathbb{R}^3$. After that is rather strange and I dont know how to work from there

Answer (score 1):

For proving these integrals exist or don't exist, all you need is that the surface area of an $n$ dimensional ball is $kr^{n-1}$ for some constant $k$.  The constants are known, but not important here.  Because of the symmetry, your integral becomes $\int_{D_R} \frac 1{r^a} kr^{n-1}dr$ where the $k$ comes from all the angular variables.  This will exist for any $a$ unless the region goes off to infinity, so is the exterior of some ball.  Your question on the interior works the same way.

Comment: I didn't really understand the symmetry part, could you explain a little more? Thanks

Comment: @diff_math:   If you think of integrating $f(r)$ over a ball in $Bbb R^3$, the integral is $4\pi \int f(r)r^2dr$ where the $4\pi$ is the surface area of a sphere and comes from integrating over the angular variables $\theta$ and $\phi$.  In your question, the first $D_R$ is not specified to be spherically symmetric, but the second one is.  But to get the answer you want it might as well be-you need the volume to go off to infinity in all directions and and asymmetry in the interior will just make a finite change to the integral, not change whether it exists or not.

Comment: what is $BbbR^3$ ? And what is the second $D_R$ ? as fair as I know there is only one.

Comment: There is other detail I dont get. If $D_R$ is a region in $R^n$, how can the integral be a one variable integral? Because $r\in\mathbb{R}$, shouldn't be $r\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to this integral makes sense? 
Im a bit confused...

Comment: @diff_math:  $BbbR^3$ was supposed to be $\Bbb R^3$ but I forgot the backslash.  The second $D_R$ was your $B_R(0)$-I didn't look back.  The integral is one dimensional because all the other dimensions have been integrated over already.  That is where the $4 \pi$ came from in my last commment.  It is $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos \theta d\theta d\phi$